# Controls several parameters from 0 to 1

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I want to achieve this effect

[image]

I've tried

```
With[{n=5},Manipulate[Table[If[0<=i-j<=1,Mod[i,1],1],{j,0,If[i<=n-1,i,n-1]}],{i,0,n}]]
```

That last one is always wrong, and I feel there must be a neat way to do it. Do you have a better way?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
With[{n = 5}
 , Manipulate[
  ConstantArray[1, IntegerPart[i]]~Join~
    {If[i > 0, FractionalPart[i], 0]} /. {a__, 0 | 0.} :> {a}
  , {{i, 1}, 0, n}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you are after?

```
With[{n = 5},
 Manipulate[
  Table[
   If[0 <= i - j <= 1, Mod[i, 1], 1],
   {j, 0,
    If[i <= n - 1, i, n - 1]}
   ],
  {i, 0, n + 0.1}
  ]
 ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 4):

## [`IntegerPart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPart.html)and [`FractionalPart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FractionalPart.html)

After the correction by @cvgmt (Thanks!)

```
Manipulate[
    Append[
        ConstantArray[1,IntegerPart[k]],
        If[ #>0, #, Nothing ]& @ FractionalPart[k]
    ] 
    , {k, 0, 5}
]
```

[image]

---

#### Old answer

My better or slightly wrong original answer, depending on the interpretation. It fails because when `k==5`, the result should be `{1,1,1,1,1}` instead of `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.}`, as commented by @cvgmt

```
Manipulate[
    Append[
        ConstantArray[1,IntegerPart[k]],
        FractionalPart[k]
    ] 
    , {k, 0, 5}
]
```

One could argue that the sequence that makes most sense should always end in a float, but that is subject to discussion and the OP's example doesn't behave like that.

Comment: When `k==5`, the result should be `{1,1,1,1,1}` instead of `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.}`

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks, corrected!

Answer (score 4):

```
Manipulate[
 If[i == 0, {N@i}, 
  If[0 < FractionalPart[i] < 1, 
   Join[ConstantArray[1, IntegerPart[i]], {FractionalPart[i]}], 
   ConstantArray[1, IntegerPart[i]]]], {i, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Same problem as mine? For `k==4` you get `{1,1,1,1,0}`

Comment: @rhermans  Thanks, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

## Using [`QuotientRemainder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuotientRemainder.html) and [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
Manipulate[
    ReplaceAll[
        QuotientRemainder[k, 1],
        RuleDelayed[
            n_Integer,
            Sequence@@ConstantArray[1,n]
        ]
    ]
    , {k, 0, 5}
]
```

or the same in compact form

```
Manipulate[
    QuotientRemainder[k, 1] /. n_Integer :> Sequence@@ConstantArray[1,n]  
    , {k, 0, 5}
]
```

Notice how `n_Integer :> Sequence@@ConstantArray[1,n]` removes the zeros too, because it replaces the zero with `Sequence@@ConstantArray[1,0]` which evaluates to `Sequence[]` which effectively removes it.

```
{4,0} /. n_Integer :> Sequence@@ConstantArray[1,n]
(* {1,1,1,1} *)
```

[image]